# .hword endianness on ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, endianness

I'm mastering my assembly, using Raspberry Pi 3 and confused with endianness of the values in literal pool.

As showed, my system is little-endian:

```
~ $ lscpu
Architecture:        armv7l
Byte Order:          Little Endian
...
```

Here is part of my code:

```
hostaddr:
        .hword 2
        .hword 0x115c   //4444
        .word 0
```

After comilation objdump showes me:

```
000100a8 <hostaddr>:
   100a8:       115c0002        .word   0x115c0002
   100ac:       00000000        .word   0x00000000
```

That seems ok, but during execution with strace it smashes the value:

```
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET,                // 0x02
    sin_port=htons(23569),                 // 0x5c11
    sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16)
```

Does it mean that I should respect endianness leaving value in literal pool?
Why 0x0002(AF_INET) was not swapped in that case?

Thanks!

Comment: The port needs to be in network byte order, meaning big endian. See [man 7 ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)

Comment: oh, true. @Jester, could you post your comment as an answer, so I could mark it as the right one?